# What are the common security issues that has to be addressed for Android mobile client app of an web application?

Tags: android, security, android-permissions

I am developing a Android mobile application for the web app. What are the common security issues that has to be addressed in the android version of it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, per my understanding android doesn't have any 'specific' security issues.
Most common seems to be:

- Storing unencrypted data (especially, logins/passwords);
- Using http instead of https;

also, checkout [this article](http://www.informationweek.com/security/vulnerabilities/popular-android-apps-vulnerable/240009507).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Android has several things you need to be aware of in addition to the two mentioned by sandrstar

1. Intent spoofing
2. Unauthorized intent receipt
3. SQL Injection and Query String Injection
4. Persistent messages: Sticky Broadcast

See: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~emc/slides/SevenWaysToHangYourselfWithGoogleAndroid.pdf for a review of the different vulnerabilities and remidiations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at the following project:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project

Any questions, just let me know.

Thanks
Fabio
@fcerullo